# When a beta stack overflow fails to meet beta requirements and gets deleted, can it go through approval again?

Tags: discussion

I'm pretty worried that the [Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) site is going to get deleted, as it's failing to meet beta requirements.

Comment: What would be different the second time around?

Comment: I don't think anything immediately would happen the second time around. But after 6 months or so, it could get potentially enough interested users again.

Answer (score 7):

This is answered in

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/

> As long as the questions and answers are of high quality, and people get answers to their questions, you shouldn’t worry about the site actually being closed. **However, Astronomy will probably stay in beta longer than average to make sure it builds up a solid user base.** And that’s the good news: by this criteria, almost all of the current sites should be allowed to continue.

Answer (score 2):

If a beta is canceled I don't think they're going to just relist it; that would kind of defeat the point. However, they do tend to let betas go on for a while if it looks like the site will make it eventually; some sites have been in beta [nearly a year](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)